# tkinter show string by condition (radiobutton, togglebutton)

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I have some problems here with the logic of tkinter. I'm trying to output a string depending on which radio button is clicked. Unfortunately the combination of the radio button with the toggle button doesn't really work and it also does not reset the text when btn or btn1 are no longer active.

```
Q1 + btn(true) = String 
Q1 + btn(false) = String1 
Q2 + btn(true) = String 
Q2 + btn(false) = String1 
Q3 + btn(true) = String 
Q3 + btn(false) = String1

Q4 = String1 
Q5 = String1 
Q6 = String2 
Q7 = String1 
Q8 = String2
```

Q4 to Q8 are not affected by btn, but all are affected by btn1

if btn1 is true, then the displayed text is to be manipulated. Example: String 1 becomes string 2 etc. If string 3 is already displayed, then it should stay that way. String 3 the last status string the first

Thanks in advance for your help. I appreciate it

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
ws = Tk()
ws.title('Logic_stuff')
#ws.geometry('800x780')
ws.option_add("*tearOff", False) # This is always a good idea
ws.configure(bg="#c7f1cd")
#create variable
text = StringVar()
varRadio = StringVar()
btn = IntVar()
btn1 = IntVar()
# Make the app responsive
ws.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
ws.columnconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
ws.columnconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
ws.rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
ws.rowconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
ws.rowconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
# Create a style
style = ttk.Style(ws)
# Create controll variables
label = Label(ws,text='empty', textvariable=text, font=("Arial", 25))
#create text variable
text = StringVar()
# Import the tcl file
ws.tk.call('source', os.path.join(dir_path, 'forest-light.tcl'))
# Set the theme with the theme_use method
style.theme_use("forest-light")
# Panedwindow
paned = ttk.PanedWindow(ws)
paned.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=1, pady=(5, 5), sticky="nsew", rowspan=3)
pane_2 = ttk.Frame(paned)
paned.add(pane_2, weight=3)
# Notebook
notebook = ttk.Notebook(pane_2)
# Tab #1
tab_1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab_1.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
tab_1.columnconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=3, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=4, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=5, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=6, weight=1)
tab_1.rowconfigure(index=7, weight=1)
notebook.add(tab_1, text="Generator")
def string():
    return Label(tab_1, text="String 1").grid(row=10, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
def string1():
    return Label(tab_1, text="String 2").grid(row=10, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
def string2():
    return Label(tab_1, text="String 3").grid(row=10, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
#Radiobuttons
radio_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1, text="Q1", variable=varRadio, value="1")
radio_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
radio_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1, text="Q2", variable=varRadio, value=" 2")
radio_2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
radio_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1, text="Q3", variable=varRadio, value="3")
radio_3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew", )
radio_4 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1, command=string1,text="Q4", variable=varRadio,value="4")
radio_4.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
radio_5 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1,command=string1, text="Q5",variable=varRadio, value="5")
radio_5.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
radio_6 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1,command=string2, text="Q6",variable=varRadio, value="6")
radio_6.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
radio_7 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1, command=string1, text="Q7",variable=varRadio, value="7")
radio_7.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
radio_8 = ttk.Radiobutton(tab_1, command=string2,text="Q8",variable=varRadio, value="8")
radio_8.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=1, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
# Togglebutton
button = ttk.Checkbutton(tab_1, command=text,text="toggleButton", style="ToggleButton", variable=btn)
button.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=5, pady=1, sticky="nsew")
button1 = ttk.Checkbutton(tab_1, text="toggleButton1", style="ToggleButton", variable=btn1)
button1.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=1, sticky="nsew")
x = varRadio.get()
text = ttk.Label(tab_1, text=x)
text.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=50, pady=100, sticky="nsew")
y = btn.get()
text = ttk.Label(tab_1, text=y)
text.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=50, pady=100, sticky="nsew") 
# Tab #2
tab_2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab_2, text="Descriotion")
# Tab #3
tab_3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab_3, text="Contact")
#add text
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)
# Center the window, and set minsize
ws.update()
ws.minsize(ws.winfo_width(), ws.winfo_height())
x_cordinate = int((ws.winfo_screenwidth()/2) - (ws.winfo_width()/2))
y_cordinate = int((ws.winfo_screenheight()/2) - (ws.winfo_height()/2))
ws.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x_cordinate, y_cordinate))
ws.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way here. In one of my other posts was in principle already the solution

Only the number of variables had to be adjusted and changed to the new .grid.

So it went like this:

Create a config with all possible combinations, query these values and pass them to the label field. But the values of the radiobuttons must be different. So here 1 - 8 .

You can see the other post here. The logic is the same:

[Python Checkboxes with tkinter and If Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71319679/python-checkboxes-with-tkinter-and-if-condition)